# Isomorphism of Hom?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-topology, vector-space-isomorphism

How do you show that $$\operatorname{Hom} (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}) \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$$?

What is the explicit isomorphism?

I'm trying to understand the concept of the cotangent bundle $T^{*}M$ for a manifold $M$, and I'm told that $T^{*}M$ is just the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\operatorname{Hom} (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$, so that for each vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have an associated element in $\operatorname{Hom} (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$. I suppose I'm a bit confused as to why this defines the cotangent bundle properly. I know that $T^{*}M$ is the set of pairs $(x,\eta) \in M \times T^{*}M$. How does this isomorphism give our definition of a linear functional in this cotangent bundle?

Comment: $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})\cong \text{Mat}_{1\times n}(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 4):

This is a special case of the usual result

> If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$ then $V\cong\mathrm{Hom}(V,K)$

How do we get the isomorphism?  Pick a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $V$.  Then let $v_i^*:V\to K$ be the map sending $\sum \lambda_j v_j$ to $\lambda_i$.

Then you can show that $v_1^*,\dots,v_n^*$ is a basis for $\textrm{Hom}(V,K)$, and the map 
$$\sum \lambda_i v_i \mapsto \sum \lambda_i v_i^*$$
is the desired isomorphism.

Importantly, you *do* need to pick a basis first in order to get an isomorphism - there is no canonical isomorphism between $V$ and $\textrm{Hom}(V,K)$, just one corresponding to each choice of basis on $V$.

Comment: Does this generalize for finite-dimensional topological vector spaces?

Comment: @Anthony For a finite dimensional normed space $V$, the dimensions of $V$ and $V^*=\textrm{Hom}(V,\mathbb R)$ are the same, by the above.  Then appeal to the result that any two finite-dimensional normed spaces of the same dimension are equivalent.

Comment: For more general finite-dimensional topological vector spaces, probably not.

Answer (score 2):

An explicit isomorphism $F:\hom(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R^n$ is given by

$$F(A)=(A(e_1),\dots,A(e_n))$$

where $A\in\hom(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$ and $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

Its inverse is 
$$v\to A_v\qquad A_v(w)=\langle v,w\rangle$$ where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the standard scalar product of $\mathbb R^n$